# How to avoid not displaying Zero in C?

Tags: c

Suppose that I want to send data from my PC to UART using C: This is an example:

```
unsigned int test[1];
test[0]= '\x06';
xprintf ("%2x \n", test[0]);
```

The result is: 6 but I need to have 06

I don't know how to resolve that. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: And why python tag?

Comment: Is it C or Python?

Comment: It is C, sorry it was mymistake

Answer (score 4):

You want this:

```
%.2x
```

But really you want to just read the docs for `printf()`.

Comment: It doesn't work, but now I find this %02X It works perfectly.